# Problem with cutomizing ErrorAttributeOptions in Spring Reactive

Tags: java, spring, spring-reactive

In my handler function I have this method

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> itemsEx(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    throw new RuntimeException("RuntimeException Occured");
}
```

Now, I want to handle this exception, so I override `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler` and create this class.

```
package com.learnreactivespring.learnreactivespring.exception;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.boot.web.error.ErrorAttributeOptions;
import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Map;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class FunctionalErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {


public FunctionalErrorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes,
                                          ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                                          ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {
    super(errorAttributes, new ResourceProperties(), applicationContext);
    super.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
    super.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
}

@Override
protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);

}

private  Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

    ErrorAttributeOptions errorAttributes = ErrorAttributeOptions.of(ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.MESSAGE);

    Map<String, Object> errorAttributesMap = getErrorAttributes(serverRequest, errorAttributes);
    log.info("errorAttributesMap : " + errorAttributesMap);

    return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorAttributesMap.get("message")));

}
```

The problem is, that **I have still a Stacktrace in my termina**l... but I explicitly defined ErrorAttributeOptions only with message.
My current version of Spring Boot is **2.3.1.RELEASE**. In previous version (2.1.1) I didn't have this problem because I used to this

```
package com.learnreactivespring.exception;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.template.TemplateAvailabilityProviders;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.Map;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class FunctionalErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {


    public FunctionalErrorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes,
                                              ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                                              ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {
        super(errorAttributes, new ResourceProperties(), applicationContext);
        super.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        super.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);

    }

    private  Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

        Map<String, Object> errorAttributesMap = getErrorAttributes(serverRequest, false);
        log.info("errorAttributesMap : " + errorAttributesMap);

        return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(errorAttributesMap.get("message")));

    }


}
```

Now, after bumped version of Spring Boot this issue occured.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults()`. But note that by default message is always empty (and stacktrace is not present).

So you probably want to use something like this:

```
ErrorAttributeOptions options = ErrorAttributeOptions
    .defaults()
    .including(ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.MESSAGE)
;
```

And use `.excluding(.)` if you want to exclude something.