# Spring Boot Upgrade causing issues with getErrorAttributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

We are upgrading `springboot` from `2.3.12 RELEASE` to `2.7.12` version. After the upgrade we face the following issues in custom exception controller class named `SampleExceptionController`

```
SampleExceptionController.java:36: error:incompatible types:boolean cannot be converted to ErrorAttributeOptions
```

The code snippet from SampleExceptionController is

```
@RestController
public class SampleExceptionController extends BasicErrorController{

@PostMapping
private ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> appExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest request){

36: Map<String, Object> body = getErrorAttributes(request, isIncludeStackTrace(request,MediaType.APPLICATION.JSON));
  
String errMsg = String.valueOf(body.get("message"));
int result = (int)body.get("status");

return ResonseEntity.status(HttpStatus.valueOf(result)).body(new ErrorMessage(result,errMsg));

}
```

Here isIncludeStackTrace method returns boolean and it is a method present in BasicErrorController class

getErrorAttributes method is present in AbstractErrorController class and the implementation is

```
protected Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, ErrorAttributeOptions options){ }
```

But the same code was working fine before springboot upgrade

I could not get what is the problem, can anyone help here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have removed isIncludeStackTrace method and modified the code as below

```
ErrorAttributeOptions options = ErrorAttributeOptions
    .defaults()
    .including(ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.STACK_TRACE);
Map<String, Object> body = getErrorAttributes(request, options);
```

Reference Link - [Problem with cutomizing ErrorAttributeOptions in Spring Reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289130/problem-with-cutomizing-errorattributeoptions-in-spring-reactive)